# Where should I connect a second slave phone box?

Tags: telephone, phone-wiring

Hi I'm new to doing diy jobs, but I already wired up a slave phone line to the master box. I'm now looking to wire a 3rd box up, would I wire this off the slave box or the master ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simple telephone service it doesn't matter.  You can run them all to one point or chain from one to the next; whichever is easiest to run.

For more advanced use of the phone wiring like DSL, having the shortest total path of wire to the demarc point is preferable, with as few splices as possible, which usually means running a cable from each jack to near the demarc point, usually in an electrical room or basement.

Running them all to that point also means if a wire breaks it only takes out that jack, not all the ones downstream of it.

Comment: Most new construction here (Canada), thankfully, runs a separate line from each jack to a common point (usually beside electrical panel), and same for cable and ethernet jacks. If you're running cable back to a central point, you should consider using ethernet (Cat5e or Cat6) as then it can be used for computer networks (LAN) but is still compatible with regular phones.

Comment: Yes for new construction definitely run seperate wires back to the electrical room area.  But if adding the jacks with walls in place either way will work just fine for phone service.

Comment: For DSL you want to minimize reflections: no stub ends.  Star wiring is best.